# How to link 2 labels in 2 different forms

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, label

I have a timer running on form 1 with a label called "timenumber" showing the time, i also have a second form that has a label "timer". How do i link these in a way that they both so the same value at the same time. Form 1 is used as a controller and the form 2 is the one that is displayed in another monitor.

Comment: Can you share your code and explain the problem with bit more details?

Comment: 2 forms with 1 label each the text in form 1's changes as a timer runs. Form 2 has only a label. I would like to link these in a way when form 1's label changes it changes Form 2's label as well. In a way linking the 2.

Comment: Does this labels show the actual time?. If that's the case why don't you point to Datetime.Now??. If not, you can have a static variable holding the "time" and then set the Text property of the label to point to that variable

Comment: @NicoRiff It is a countdown timer.

Comment: Is `form1` that creates/shows `form2`?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, form1 opens form2. all the functionality is in form1. All i need is to make the labels same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
Pass a reference to the Count Down Label in `Form1` to `Form2` using its constructor, then use this reference to subscribe to the Label's `TextChanged` event:

In **`Form1`**:

```
private int CountDown = 100;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(this.[The Counter Label]);
    form2.Show();
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.[The Counter Label].Text = CountDown.ToString();
    if (CountDown == 0)
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;
    CountDown -= 1;
}
```

In **`Form2`**:

```
public form2() : this(null) { }

public form2(Control timerCtl)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (timerCtl != null) {
        timerCtl.TextChanged += (s, evt) => { this.[Some Label].Text = timerCtl.Text; };
    }
}
```

**Option 2**
Use a Public Property of `Form2` that can be set to a Control reference. Set this property in `Form1` right after a new instance of `Form2` has beed created.
This, however, implies that `Form1` needs to *know* about this property in `Form2`:

In **`Form1`**:

```
private int CountDown = 100;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
    form2.CountDownControl = this.[The Counter Label];
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.[The Counter Label].Text = CountDown.ToString();
    if (CountDown == 0)
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;
    CountDown -= 1;
}
```

In **`Form2`**:

```
private Control timerCtl = null;

public Control CountDownControl {
    set { this.timerCtl = value;
        if (value != null) {
            this.timerCtl.TextChanged += (s, evt) => { this.[Some Label].Text = timerCtl.Text; };
        }
    }
}
```

Many other options exist.

You could also use a Public Property in `Form2` and set this property directly from the `Timer.Tick` event. The public property, as in the second example, could set the Text property of one of its controls to the value of the property.
I don't like this option very much, nonetheless it's available.

In **`Form1`**:

```
private int CountDown = 100;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
    this.timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.[The Counter Label].Text = CountDown.ToString();
    form2?.CountDownValue = CountDown;
    if (CountDown == 0)
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;
    CountDown -= 1;
}
```

In **`Form2`**:

```
public int CountDownValue {
    set { this.[Some Label].Text = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

You could also have a custom event in `Form1` that `Form2` could subscribe, or implement **`INotifyPropertyChange`**. But this is, give or take, the same thing as Option1.

Answer (score 0):

If `form1` opens `form2`, this is easy. In `Form2`, define a property to set the text on the label:

```
public string TimerText 
{
  set => _timerLabel.Text = value;
}
```

You might also need to call `_timerLabel.Invalidate();` to force the label to refresh.

Then, when the countdown timer in `form1` updates, simply set that property in `form2`:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // calculate remaining time
  _form2.TimerText = remainingTime.ToString();
}
```

Here, `_form2` is a reference to the `Form2` object that `form1` is showing.

You could have the property in `Form2` be an `int` or `double` rather than a `string`; which you choose may depend on whether you do anything else with the value in `Form2`.